# Left Outer Join returns duplicate records - Oracle

Tags: oracle, duplicates, left-join

Scenario :

Join Table ORDER with Table COST 
where COST has multiple rows for a single reference from Table ORDER

Desired outcome:

Return single row per Order with its associated costs.

```
ID NAME PRICE GST
1  Book 100   10
2  CD   50    5
```

Ex:

Table ORDER

```
ID   NAME  COST
1    Book  110
2    CD    55
```

Table COST

```
ID ORDER_ID COST_TYPE VALUE
1   1   PRICE      100
2   1   GST        10
3   2   PRICE      50
4   2   GST        5
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN returns multiple rows when below condition is used

```
SELECT * from ORDER
LEFT OUTER JOIN COST
ON ORDER.ID = COST.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: Well what are you expecting it to return, and show output?

Comment: What do you want it to return? currently you are selecting all records from both tables, i'm not even sure if this works since I think you need to specify which table you're selecting the column from.

Comment: Ah! you guys are too quick :) I actually found the solution for this, wanted to create a question so that it could help others.

Comment: More specifically: what do you mean by "its associated costs"? In the second table you have values for `PRICE` and `GST` (whatever that means). How are those, if in any way, related to **associated costs**?

Comment: OK with the edit...  What version of Oracle do you use? Oracle 11.1 and higher have the `PIVOT` operator; for earlier versions you need to use conditional aggregation.

Comment: Hi. Why *wouldn't* this return duplicates? And what does "return duplicates" mean? [mcve] please. And telling that you vaguely want a join is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
select o.id, o.name, c.price, c.gst
from   order o left outer join
       ( select   order_id, 
                  sum(case when cost_type = 'PRICE' then value end) as price,
                  sum(case when cost_type = 'GST'   then value end) as gst
         from     cost
         group by order_id
       ) c
       on o.id = c.order_id
;
```

Comment: Yes, this is more efficient. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So `Select ORDER.ID, COST.COST_TYPE, COST.VALUE from ORDERS LEFT OUTER JOIN COST ON ORDER.ID = COST.ORDER_ID and COST.COST_TYPE = 'PRICE'`

If you don't specify `COST_TYPE` then it will return multiple rows because `ORDER_ID` repeats on your COST TABLE.

Comment: Are you sure PRICE and COST are the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found working in my case.

Had to use 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN's and alias to get it working

```
SELECT ID, NAME, PRICE.value as PRICE, GST.value as GST 
from ORDER

LEFT OUTER JOIN COST as PRICE
ON ORDER.ID = COST.ORDER_ID
AND PRICE.COST_TYPE = 'PRICE'

LEFT OUTER JOIN COST as GST
ON ORDER.ID = COST.ORDER_ID
AND GST.COST_TYPE = 'GST'
```

Comment: So the solution I offered didn't work? Or did you not even try it? For the record - the solution you found is correct, but inefficient. It performs two joins instead of just one, which also means it must do a full scan on the second table twice instead of just once.